# Problem with EnableDelayedExpansion, For, and filenames with special characters like ! % &

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**The Setup:**

1. I have a set of files of type `.type1` and want to batch convert them to `.type2` using a program I have
2. The converting program `Program.exe` (in a folder called `TOOLS`) takes two arguments `-i` for InputFile and `-o` for OutputFile but is unable to create folders/directories (if the output folder doesn't exist it fails)
3. The `.type1` files are in different folders. All of these folders are in a folder called `InputFolder`
4. I want the `.type2` converted files to be outputted to the `OutputFolder` preserving the folder structure of the originals
5. So, In the main folder I have 4 things:- 
   `A. InputFolder` :where all the input files (divided into different folders) exist 
   `B. OutputFolder`:where all the converted files should be outputted (divided into different folders matching the `InputFolder`)
   `C. TOOLS` :where the converter `Program.exe` exists
   `D. Batch Convert.bat` :the batch file I wrote to batch convert the files. The contents of which are in the next section

**What I tried:**

```
rem -------Setting some general variables-------
set "BatchPath=%~dp0"
set "InputPath=%BatchPath%InputFolder\"
set "OutputPath=%BatchPath%OutputFolder\"

rem -------Saving a list of all .type1 files-------
dir /s/b/a-d "%InputPath%*.type1">"%BatchPath%TOOLS\FilesList.txt"

rem -------Starting a loop for each file listed in FilesList.txt -------
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%BatchPath%TOOLS\FilesList.txt") do (

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem --Setting variables replacing "input string" with "output string"--
set "InputFileType2=%%~dpnj.type2"
set "OutputFile=!InputFileType2:%InputPath%=%OutputPath%!"

set "InputFilePath=%%~dpj"
set "OutputFilePath=!InputFilePath:%InputPath%=%OutputPath%!"

rem --Creating output folders--
mkdir "!OutputFilePath!"

rem --Start the converting process--
"%BatchPath%TOOLS\Program.exe" -i "%%j" -o "!OutputFile!"

endlocal
)
```

**The Problem:**
Some of the folders and the files inside the `InputFolder` have special characters (like `! % &`) which cause problems with the converting.
Is there a way to do this with the least amount of conflict with special characters (like removing the need to `EnableDelayedExpansion` to remove conflict with `!`?
is there a way to do it without the PwerShell or the `Call` function?
(because I have thousands of big files and the `Call` function can be slow and it seems like it always tries to access the HDD first before a `:Label`)

Comment: Delayed expansion has to be disabled when you assign the value to the variable and then enabled after that. Another option you can try with delayed expansion disabled is `CALL set "OutputFile=%%InputFileType2:%InputPath%=%OutputPath%%%"`. The call command with the double percent symbols allows for two phases of variable expansion.

Comment: You have a typo as well: `InputPath1`.

Comment: I would also suggest that instead of creating a text file from the `DIR` command you just use a `FOR /R` command. `FOR /R "%InputPath%" %%G IN (*.type1) DO .....`

Comment: @Squashman apparently I typed that while posting the question, I'll correct it. Thank you for the correction and suggestions

Comment: Move `set "InputFileType2=%%~dpnj.type2"` and `set "InputFilePath=%%~dpj"` above the line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, and you will not have any issues with `!` characters in those value strings.

Answer (score 1):

As compo said, you just need to change the order of lines.
It's important to expand the FOR variables only with delayed expansion disabled.
Because expanding them inside delayed expansion enabled, destroys the exclamation marks `!`

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%BatchPath%TOOLS\FilesList.txt") do (
 
  rem --Setting variables replacing "input string" with "output string"--
  set "InputFileType2=%%~dpnj.type2"
  set "OutputFile=!InputFileType2:%InputPath%=%OutputPath%!"

  set "InputFilePath=%%~dpj"
  set "helper=%%j"

  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    set "OutputFilePath=!InputFilePath:%InputPath%=%OutputPath%!"

    rem --Creating output folders--
    mkdir "!OutputFilePath!"

    rem --Start the converting process--
    "%BatchPath%TOOLS\Program.exe" -i "!helper!" -o "!OutputFile!"

  endlocal
)
```